# Java: Testing Concrete Class passing by Interface, Mockito, JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, interface, mockito

I have this interface:

```
public interface RepositoryUserDB {

    User createUser(User user);
}
```

and the method implemented into the following class:

```
public class MemoryUserDB implements RepositoryUserDB{

    Map<String, User> repo = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public User createUser(User user) {
        return repo.put(user.getUsername(), user);
    }
}
```

The target is to test the method. I started to write this, but I think it is not correct:

```
@Test
public void testCreateUser(){
    User result = new User("luca", "antico", "23.11.2011", "112");
    Assert.assertEquals("luca", result.getUsername());
}
```

How can I accomplish it?

Thanks

edit:

the class User:

```
 public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String SSN;

    public User(String username, String password, String dateOfBirth, String SSN) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.SSN = SSN;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getSSN() {
        return SSN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your repository behaves strangely. I would expect it to return some wrapped or otherwise proxied instance of the thing I pass into `save`. Instead your's returns the previous instance bound to that key, or `null`. Very odd.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: it is an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, that test does not add much of a value.

What you should aim for is to verify whether the repo contains the user that you have passed through that method.

Assuming you have some kind of `getByUserName` method on that repo, and the User class has `equals` and `hashCode` properly defined, you could go for a test like this:

```
private MemoryUserDB memoryUserDB;

@Test
public void shouldCreateUser(){
   // Arrange
   User user = new User("luca", "antico", "23.11.2011", "112");

   // Act
   User addedUser = memoryUserDB.createUser(user);

   // Assert
   assertEquals(user, addedUser);
   assertEquals(user, memoryUserDB.getByUsername("luca");
}
```

Also try not to put `test` in your test method names, try to explain the bahavior through the name.

Comment: I have this report
`java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :app.model.User@41975e01
Actual   :null`

Comment: try to debug and see what is the problem.. thats what the unit tests are for

Comment: addedUser results null, anyway thank you, I will try to fix it... It was important to know how to organise the test.

Comment: maybe I understood why the second variable is null, because this is a map and we can't add two keys with the same value. So, what I have to do now?